# Why the Search Function for Random user api is not working?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on random user api, the fetching of user name and pagination is working fine but not the search event. Please help.
I pushed my code on stackblitz, to help you guys to debug it easily.

here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/search-and-pagination-in-react-by-react-hooks?file=src/App.js

below in image you can see that the name i mentioned in search box is present in api but its not comming on first place.

[image]

Comment: what is not working? i can see searching is working properly. just it is searching the names that include the search input string

Comment: really ?, its seriously not working in my case. let me provide a screenshot of whats happening.

Comment: Add `searchUser` in the `useEffect`'s dependency array as your user fetching logic is getting called only on the initial render due to dependency array being empty.

Comment: @usafder thanks a lot it worked, also i think i should customize my search box as a form so that i can avoid refreshing of api page on every single user input.

Comment: Np. Should I post it as an answer so you can mark it as the accepted solution ? :)

Comment: @usafder yeah no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're `useEffect` has `[]` (empty array) as the dependency, you're user fetching logic will only be called once i.e. on the initial rendering. You can add `searchUser` as `useEffect`'s dependency so you can fetch users whenever the `searchUser` text changes.

Answer (score 2):

[Working example in here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/search-and-pagination-in-react-by-react-hooks-1gdrca?file=src/App.js).

```
const App = () => {
  const [myApi, setMyApi] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // add your data to here
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [searchUser, setSearchUser] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(json_result => {
        setData(json_result.results);  // set your data to state
        let myApi = renderData(json_result.results);  // render your component
        setMyApi(myApi); // set it to state
      });
  }, []);

  const renderData = (data) => {
     return data.map((item, idx) => {
            return (
              <div key={idx}>
                <img src={item.picture.thumbnail} alt="" /> {item.name.first}
                <hr />
              </div>
            );
          });
  }

  // get current post
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage; // 1 * 10 = 10
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage; // 10 - 10 = 0
  const currentPosts = myApi?.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost); // 0 to 10

  // search users by user input
  const handleSearchInput = event => {
    setSearchUser(event.target.value);
    const newData = renderData(data.filter(item => item.name.first.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value)));  // render filtered data
    setMyApi(newData); // and set it to state
  };

  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  return (
    <div>
      <Search onChange={handleSearchInput} />
      <Pagination
        postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
        totalPosts={myApi?.length}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
      {currentPosts}
    </div>
  );
};

const Search = ({ onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        autoFocus={true}
        placeholder="search users"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some explanation of why this code addresses the OP's issue?

Comment: @YashMarmat any time bro.